# how to rectify Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp64\www\Form\addtodatabase.php on line 12 error

Tags: php, html, post

There is a page called form.html .It directs to the page addtodatabase.php
at the end there is submit button .

```
    <form action="addtodatabase.php" method="post">
    <form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Security Department User Registration</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Secondname">Second Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Secondname" name="secondname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

My addtodatabase.php page .

```
    $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','form_db');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
    {
    echo 'Failed to connect:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $firstname=""; 
    $secondname="";
    if (isset($_POST)) { 
    $firstname  = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
    $secondname = isset($_POST['secondname']) ? $_POST['secondname'] : '';
    echo 'Your first name is ' .$firstname. '<br>'; 
    echo 'Your second name is ' .$secondname. '<br>'; 
    }
```

There  are three errors

> it doesn't get to the page `addtodatabase.php`.
>   http://localhost:8080/form/form.html?
>   Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp64\www\Form\addtodatabase.php on line 12.
>   nothing is being added to database. only id is increment

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you missed submit button..

Comment: If you don't get there how do you get the error/notice? Why assign `$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];` twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];//trying to initialize the variable
                      $secondname=$_POST['secondname'];//trying to initialize the variable

                        if (isset($_POST)) { 
                         $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
                         $secondname=$_POST['secondname'];

Comment: Initialize the variables with empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you access the post value, you had better check if it exists. So use

```
$firstname  = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
$secondname = isset($_POST['secondname']) ? $_POST['secondname'] : '';
```

to replace

```
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$secondname=$_POST['secondname'];
```

edit:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','form_db');

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
echo 'Failed to connect:'.mysqli_connect_error();
}


$firstname  = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
$secondname = isset($_POST['secondname']) ? $_POST['secondname'] : '';

echo 'Your first name is ' .$firstname. '<br>'; 
echo 'Your second name is ' .$secondname. '<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: where do i need to add above changes ? above isset or with the if(isset($_POST))

Comment: I edited it. when the name setted, it shows the name. if not setted, show nothing.

Comment: i have changed my code as per above code i dont have this undefined index error . Data doesn't get  added  form_details neither increments the id .

Comment: There may other issues in your code.  You can use log to find them.

Comment: what is log ? is it the software or some tool to  debugg

Answer (score 0):

**Note- Check isset before get data.**

**Try this**

```
 $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','form_db');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
    {
    echo 'Failed to connect:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if (isset($_POST)) { 
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $secondname=$_POST['secondname'];


    echo 'Your first name is ' .$firstname. '<br>'; 
    echo 'Your second name is ' .$secondname. '<br>'; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

is addtodatabase.php in the same folder as form.html?

if html is in c:\wamp64\www and addtodatabase.php is in C:\wamp64\www\Form\ then change the html to;

```
<form action="Form/addtodatabase.php" method="post">
<form class="form-inline">
<fieldset>
<legend>Security Department User Registration</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="Secondname">Second Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Secondname" name="secondname" placeholder="Text input"><br/>
</div>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how will you submit this form?

Comment: Opps didnt see that, I have changed the code, thanks Sunil.